# How to work around java workspace and change to double

Tags: java

so I have to write a program that asks the user to enter in the number of students, then asks to input name of first student and then asks the grade of the student, then it goes on to the next student. For example it asks how many students and I say 5, then it asks me the name of the first student, and I say bob smith, then it asks me the grade, so I say 12.5, then it asks me the next students name and so on till I finish all five students. It then sorts everyone in descending order by their grade. I have it working, but there are two problems. 1.I cant put in a first and last name because of the white space. It works fine if I put in bob but not when I put bob smith. 2. I cant get it to read in double variables for the grade, only int. so 5 works but not 5.3.Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class assignment5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of students: ");
        int numofstudents = input.nextInt();
        String[] names = new String[numofstudents];
        int[] array = new int[numofstudents];
        for(int i = 0; i < numofstudents; i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter the student's name: ");
            names[i] = input.next();
            System.out.print("Enter the student's score: ");
            array[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        selectionSort(names, array);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
    }
    public static void selectionSort(String[] names, int[] array) {
        for(int i = array.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
            String temp;
            int currentMax = array[0];
            int currentMaxIndex = 0;
            for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++) {
                if (currentMax > array[j]) {
                    currentMax = array[j];
                    currentMaxIndex = j;
                }
            }       
            if (currentMaxIndex != i) {
                temp = names[currentMaxIndex];
                names[currentMaxIndex] = names[i];
                names[i] = temp;
                array[currentMaxIndex] = array[i];
                array[i] = currentMax;
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Scanner.nextDouble()` instead of `nextInt()`.

Answer (score 1):

For your name problem set the delimiter to end of line

```
input.useDelimiter("\\n");
```

And for the grades issue you need to make `array` variable an array of floats or doubles and then use `input.nextFloat()` or `input.nextDouble()`.

See: http://ideone.com/Qz7hD8

Comment: Or you can use nextLine() to read a whole line with multiple words (as the name)

Comment: I tried putting in the input.useDelimiter("\\n"); but it still doesn't work